# What are 'branches of equilibria' and 'branch points'?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I'm reading through an article which proposes a population interaction model for treating cancer with viral therapy with differential equations and in the bifurcation analysis they have mentioned these two concepts multiple times. I've never heard of them and I couldn't find them in any of the books I looked through.
Can anyone help out in explaining to me these concepts?

Comment: If you pick a point in parameter space and find some equilibrium in phase space, what happens when you change one of the parameter after that? If you picked an equilibrium with no zero eigenvalues in its linearization, it will just change its position in phase space tracing some smooth curve. However, what happens when equilibrium has zero eigenvalue? It could be a saddle-node bifurcation, where two distinct _branches of equilibria_ intersect at _branch point_ and might cease to exist afterwards. Also, take a look at [Doedel's lectures](http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/notes.pdf).